# How to regulate a function in python under condition?

Tags: python-3.x, function, pygame

I have a function in pygame, which I have to run when the user presses space. However, the problem is that as soon as space is pressed, the function runs much more than once. I want it to run once, and if the user presses space again, I want the function to run again - once.

Some code below

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
  God()
```

Now God() draws a bunch of shapes at the same time when I want it to draw one shape at a time, everytime the user presses space. God() is only called once. It picks a random number from 1 to 100 in order to make probabilities for each shape.

Comment: BTW, God is a function that picks a random number and draws a shape accordingly using rectangles in python. (Kind of like a tetris shape)

Comment: Have some boolean `keyPressed` that starts a `True`.  Then, when you see the key pressed, check that boolean.  If it is true, set it to `False` and call your function.  Have another event listener that checks for when the key is released, which will set the boolean to `True` again.  I suspect there's a more natural way to do this using the pygame library though.

Comment: Is the problem that a single call to `God` draws a bunch of stuff or that there are a bunch of calls to `God`?

Comment: Is the code part of an event handler?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question. Also, a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be very helpful here.

Comment: If you trigger on event type `pygame.KEYUP` you'll get around this problem.

Comment: @Eric Thanks, but I've tried that and it didn't work very well. The problem is with the function iteration, not the keys. Either way, it will keep repeating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is required for more specific assistance with your issue.

Below is an example that shows the following:

1. Holding down the <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to continually add sprites (coloured rectangles). The key down events are repeated by calling [pygame.key.set_repeat()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.set_repeat).
2. Holding down the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key will continually add sprites, but limited to once every five seconds
3. Pressing and releasing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key will generate a single sprite.

Let me know if you have any questions.

```
import random
import pygame
import time

screen_width, screen_height = 640, 480
def get_random_position():
    """return a random (x,y) position in the screen"""
    return (random.randint(0, screen_width - 1),  #randint includes both endpoints.
            random.randint(0, screen_height - 1)) 

def get_random_named_color(allow_grey=False):
    """return one of the builtin colors"""
    if allow_grey:
        return random.choice(all_colors)
    else:
        return random.choice(non_grey)

def non_grey(color):
    """Return true if the colour is not grey/gray"""
    return "grey" not in color[0] and "gray" not in color[0]

all_colors = list(pygame.colordict.THECOLORS.items())  
# convert color dictionary to a list for random selection once
non_grey = list(filter(non_grey, all_colors))

class PowerUp(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        width, height = 12, 10
        self.color, color = get_random_named_color()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)
        # Fetch the rectangle object that has the dimensions of the image
        # Update the position of this object by setting the values of rect.x and rect.y
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect().move(*get_random_position())

    def update(self):
        #move to a random position
        self.rect.center = get_random_position()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Sprite Collision Demo')
    clock = pygame.time.Clock() #for limiting FPS
    FPS = 60
    exit_demo = False
    regulating = False
    reg_start = 0

    pygame.key.set_repeat(300, 200)

    #pygame.mouse.set_cursor(*pygame.cursors.ball)
    #create a sprite group to track the power ups.
    power_ups = pygame.sprite.Group()
    for _ in range(10):
        power_ups.add(PowerUp()) # create a new power up and add it to the group.

    # main loop
    while not exit_demo:
        for event in pygame.event.get():            
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                exit_demo = True
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    exit_demo = True
                elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    power_ups.add(PowerUp())
                    #power_ups.update()
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    if not regulating:
                        reg_start = time.time()
                        power_ups.add(PowerUp())
                        regulating = True
                    else:
                        # limit to five seconds intervals
                        elapsed_ms = time.time() - reg_start
                        ##print("Regulating", elapsed_ms)
                        if elapsed_ms > 5:
                            regulating = False

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_TAB:
                    power_ups.add(PowerUp())                

            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                for _ in range(10):
                    power_ups.add(PowerUp())
        # check for collision
        for p in power_ups:
            if p.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                power_ups.remove(p)
                print(f"Removed {p.color} power up")

        # clear the screen with a black background
        screen.fill(pygame.Color("black"))
        # draw sprites
        power_ups.draw(screen)
        # update the surface
        pygame.display.update()
        # limit the frame rate
        clock.tick(FPS)
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got it now. I don't think I would have needed so much code, but I can use different parts of it if I need help with my game!                         PS. I am new to PyGame!

Comment: You're welcome, glad to be able to help. Good luck with your project.