# pygame random points function

Tags: for-loop, random, pygame

im trying to create a function that fill the screen with dots(that will be the points in the game)

the problem is the points created by a for loop and when i run the program the points just move around and wont stay in place.

the code:

```
def random_points():

point_x = random.randint(0, 900)
point_y = random.randint(0, 500)
rand_color = (random.random(), random.random(), (random.random()))
R = random.randint(1, 4)
for _ in range(1, 5):
    pygame.draw.circle(WIN, rand_color, (point_x, point_y), R)
```

Comment: If these dots will be points in your game, I'd recommend creating [sprites](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) and storing them in a Group for easier management, e.g. [collision detection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50224453/2280890).

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a list of points before the application loop:

```py
point_list = []
for _ in range(1, 5):
    point_x = random.randint(0, 900)
    point_y = random.randint(0, 500)
    rand_color = (random.random(), random.random(), (random.random()))
    R = random.randint(1, 4)
    point = (rand_color, (point_x, point_y), R)
    point_list.append(point)
```

Draw the points from the list in the application loop:

```py
run = True
while run:
    for event = pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    WIN.fill(0)
    for color, center, rad in point_list:
        pygame.draw.circle(WIN, color, center, rad)
    pygame.disaply.flip()
```

Comment: @Liron This is not my fault. You did it wrong. The 1st part needs to be before the application loop not in the application loop.